# Tab activate in Jquery

Tags: jquery

AM using jQuery 1.9.1. am having tabs in my application. We can move to that tabs either through a button click on previous tab or directly clickng the TAB. In both the cases i need to validate the tabs. On button click am using

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

When i click tabs am using the below code

```
 beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {}
```

Issue is, this beforeActivate is triggered on activating the tab through button click also. Is there any way to check in beforeActivate event whether the action comes from tab change or button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes make `var x=0`

on `button click` change value of `x=1`

than check `beforeActivate:`

```
beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
       if(x == 1){
         alert('tab changed by button click');
         x=0; //set value of x again to 0
       }
})
```

Comment: Tried id before. but wasnt worked .. the problem is i dint declared the variable as a global one. but now Worked. thanks.